# Почему возникает ошибка Unhandled rejection TypeError: next is not a function в моём примере?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

По одному примеру делаю маленький проект на node+express+postgres(pg-promise), пытался вывести данные в шаблон jade, получаю ошибку "Unhandled rejection TypeError: next is not a function", подскажите пожалуйста что тут не так 
queries.js:
 `var promise = require('bluebird');
          var options = {
           // Initialization Options
                   promiseLib: promise
           };

```
       var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
       var connectionString = 'postgres://guest:123@122.21.49.99:5432/alarm';
      var db = pgp(connectionString);

      function getAllAlarms(req, res, next) {
        db.any('select * from alarm')
              .then(function (data) {
                res.status(200)
                      .json({

                        data: data,

                      });

              })

              .catch(function (err) {
                return next(err);
              });
      }
```

module.exports = {
                  getAllAlarms: getAllAlarms,
};
`
routes/index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
       var router = express.Router();
       var db = require('../queries');


     // router.get('/', db.getAllAlarms);

    router.get('index', function (req, res, next) {
              db.getAllAlarms()
                .then(all_alarms => {
                  res.render('/index', { obj: all_alarms });
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                  return next(err);
                });
            });
```

module.exports = router;

index.jade:

```
html
```

head
    title= title
  body

h1= 'Alarm'
  a= {obj}
  hr

Answer (score 2):

У вас функция `function getAllAlarms(req, res, next)` принимает три аргумента.
А вызываете вы её без аргументов - `db.getAllAlarms().then(all_alarms....`
И вообще, сначала стоит определиться, вы хотите отдать json -   `res.status(200).json({data});`
или отрендерить index - 
`res.render('/index', { obj: all_alarms });`? В ваш код выглядит так, как будто вы хотите и то и другое сразу.

Comment: В первую очередь я хотел отредндерить json